# How TF-IDF handles missing values?

Tags: python-3.x, tf-idf, text-classification

I am working on a classification problem in which I have to classify product category based on the information of the product like title, description and other attributes.
It is working for different categories but getting biased in closed categories like **mobile** and **mobile accessories**.

Let's say I have a csv in which I have the following columns:

```
Title | Retailer_Name | Description | RAM | Processor | Suitable For | Price | Category
```

Now, If I have two categories say **mobile** and **fashion**. For mobile, **Suitable For** column would be NA and for fashion RAM, Processor would be NA.

*So, I wanted to know how TF-IDF works on those columns and also If there is a way to do TF-IDF on individual columns for different categories and later merge them. I found few articles, but none related to my specific problem.*

Any related articles would do. I just want to understand the working so that I can implement it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..!